# VB code to C# using WCF

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf

What is the equivalent code of this code in C#?

```
Private _RequiredDays As Integer?
Public Property RequiredDays As Integer?
    Get
        Return _RequiredDays
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer?)
        _RequiredDays = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Can anyone help me? Because I'm trying to make models in my WCF. Thanks

Comment: This is not a code conversion service.

Comment: `public int? RequiredDays { get; set; }` as an auto-property is the simplest

Comment: Goggle for vb.net to c# code converter online

Comment: Heck, even just `public int? RequiredDays;` works. `get` and `set` are automatic.

Comment: @Nyerguds but then it's a public field, not a property...

Comment: @RufusL As far as I know that's the same thing, in c#. <EDIT> Ah nope, it isn't. Guess I learned something.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int? RequiredDays { get; set; }
```

Comment: @Novice How would we know? You never specified any such thing in your original question.